# What type of circuit or component is used to sample RF power?

Tags: power, amplifier, rf, sampling, power-measurement

I'm building a 2-stage RF power amplifier and I would like to measure the RF power at each stage and report it to a microcontroller on the board:

```
  17dBm -> [amp1] -> 36dBm -> [amp2] -> 50dBm
                       |                 |
                       +-Probe1 to MCU   +- Probe2 to MCU
```

What component or circuit would you use to sample RMS power in the 150-500MHz range with minimal loss?  The output is 50-Ohm impedance, but the middle stage (Probe1) is a complex match.

Comment: There's no such thing as RMS power - average power yes, RMS power, no. RMS voltage, RMS current and RMS signal yes, but not power. Please explain what you are trying to measure.

Comment: @Andyaka: Good point.  What are amplifier wattages usually indicating?  I'm assuming average power, certainly not peak envelope power.  What is it called when multiplying RMS_Current*RMS_Voltage?

Comment: It’s called average power or just power or instantaneous power. Never rms.

Comment: @KJ7LNW Any chance you may give us a schematic for the sake of science ?
What solution have you retained to sample part of your amplifier ?

Comment: @WirelessLearning, actually haven't got that far yet.  I was looking at a device like the Guerrilla GRF1201 and then sample power using some kind of coupling next to the transmission line to minimize impedance effects. We would probably optimize the impedance coupling with something like Microwave Office's AXIEM.  If the coupling loss is enough to get below the high power of the amp into the sensitivity of the measuring chip then I can get an analog voltage from the Guerrilla indicating its measured dB and then add it to the coupled loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a couple of RF power detectors like Chengxiang mentioned, and you will also need
to add fixed RF power attenuators in series with the detectors, this is pretty much standard in the RF world, many instrumentation commercial power detectors are not able to measure more than -20dBm (i.e. Keysight, Boonton, etc..).

When you process the data just compensate for the attenuation, say you attenuated the signal 30dB and you measured 20dBm, just add the extra 30dBs you attenuated the signal and you get 50dBm. You will also need a directional coupler and it also adds attenuation which needs to be accounted for.

When it comes to power attenuators and directional couplers its best to buy rather than roll your own. Just look for the desired attenuation and power disipation capabilities, miniCircuits is a very popular brand but not the only one, Google and eBay are your friends...

Comment: Do the (attenuated) detectors just tee/tap into the signal line directly, or do I need a power divider to split some power off for sampling?  Basically I'm asking this: how would the detector+attenuator unit be wired to the feedline, and does it affect the impedance of the feedline being measured?

Comment: Both the directional couplers and the attenuators are meant to work (usually) on 50 ohm lines, so they wont "affect" the impedance of the line. The directional couplers do exhibit some insertion loss, most of the time its quite low. The coupled port ( the tap from which you measure power) does attenuate the signal, typically by 15-20dB.

Answer (score 3):

RF power detectors, like these:
https://www.analog.com/en/products/rf-microwave/rf-power-detectors.html

Comment: The dBm levels those support values are pretty low, maybe up to 12 or 20dBm input.  How could this be sampled at 100W (50 dBm)?

Comment: The OP includes the power levels in his original question.

Comment: you can make a resistive tap for low power, or this high power tap: https://www.minicircuits.com/pdfs/ZARC-26-12+.pdf

Comment: @ChengxianZhang, would an uneven Wilkinson divider be another option to split into the low power detectors?